# javascript/jquery object inside object json data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this data,

json:

```
var data = [{a:1,b:{amount: 10}, c:1},
            {a:2,b:{amount: 20}, c:1}, 
            {a:1,b:{amount: 30}, c:2}
           ];
```

and I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(b.amount) FROM data GROUP BY a, c
```

Comment: Javascript objects are not databases. Have you tried writing any code yet to implement the functionality you want?

Comment: i've tried using alaSQL.js but i just can't get the b.amount...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to sum properties in an array of objects.

This will do it for you:

```
let sum = [];
data.forEach(function(el){
    if(sum[el.a] == undefined) sum[el.a] = []; 
    if(sum[el.a][el.c] == undefined) sum[el.a][el.c] = 0; 
    sum[el.a][el.c] += el.b.amount
});
```

You can then access the sum for `a = 1`, `c = 2` with `sum[1][2]`.

This code will work with larger data sets which require adding.

Comment: Just multiply the amount by the quantity. Like this:

`sum[el.a][el.c] += el.b.amount * el.b.qty;`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions correctly, you are asking how you can perform grouping and aggregation on a JSON object. As SQL can only be used in the realm of a database, you will need to use javascript functions such as forEach(), map(), filter(), reduce(), etc.

To make it easy on yourself, I recommend using a library like [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) or [Underscore](https://underscorejs.org/).

Here is an example using Lodash:

```js
let data = [
  {a:1, b:{amount: 10}, c:1},
  {a:2, b:{amount: 20}, c:1},
  {a:1, b:{amount: 30}, c:2}
];

let results = _.sumBy(data, 'b.amount');

console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Using these libraries can take away a lot of the complexity of writing your own scripting, especially when dealing with nested objects and arrays.

I recommend using pure JS whenever possible and resort to libraries only when necessary.

Comment: ooh lodash, ya i've heard of it. i'll consider this also.. thank you